# Any app or command to view list of installed codecs

Tags: 11.10, codecs

I just wanted to know whether is it possible to view a list of codecs installed on my Ubuntu 11.10 through any command, script or app?

If you know any app even if it's in "rpm" format (I will use Alien to convert it to "Deb")  please feel free to suggest, thanks.

Regards,

Arsalan Alam

Comment: Search for Codecs in Synaptic, the reuslts will show what packages contain the codecs and what codecs are inside.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one-liner on the command-line:

```
clear; echo "Enumerating codecs.."; echo; dpkg --get-selections  | awk '{print $1}' | grep -iR codec; export number=`dpkg --get-selections  | awk '{print $1}' | grep -iR codec | wc -l`; echo; echo "$number codecs installed."; echo
```

Comment: No sweat, glad to help :)