# Why doesn't the audo utility "jack" show codecs which are installed?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack, audio-recording, zoom-meeting

When starting up `jack` with the command `hdajackretask` the `GUI` reports that there aren't any `codecs` for [recording](https://askubuntu.com/q/474799/847449) audio.  Off the top of my head, this seems nonsensical as I'm using `Text Now` and other `VoIP` apps without problem:

[image: jack]

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version (67).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 154 not upgraded.
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ uname -a
Linux mordor 5.11.0-34-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 26 19:22:09 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Admittedly, the output of a [command](https://askubuntu.com/a/118393/847449) to list codecs wasn't immediately and easily human readable -- at least to this human.

---

The `GUI` documentation shows:

> Start the application "hdajackretask" from the command line. Select  a
> codec in the top bar; some people have only one - if you have more
> than one, one is the "main" one, and the rest are probably HDMI
> codecs.

which in no way addresses the fact that *no* codecs are found by `jack` itself.

Comment: Have you tried to click on "Read documentation" button? It may be helpful.

Comment: I updated the question @N0rbert to include what the documentation shows on this topic.  Which section of the documentation were you referencing, please?

Comment: This, on [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOaPZ.png).

Comment: Yes, @N0rbert  -- that's the documentation quoted in the text of the question.